# ifelse statement returning 0 in R

Tags: r, if-statement, matrix

I am writing a conditional statement in R, to return values from one matrix, if value in other matrix is TRUE. It returns 0 every time.

I have a  temperature table of an image, and also table that shows cluster for each point. I want to extract temperature info data only from points in cluster 3.

```
asc <- read_excel("V:ascii_temp.xlsx") 
b <- df$cluster=="3" # image segmenting result. Taking only cluster 3, matrix 1
m <- as.matrix(asc) # matrix 2
cond <- ifelse(b=="TRUE",m,0)
```

Comment: Perhaps you should be using `TRUE` without double quotes around it, i.e. `ifelse(b==TRUE, m, 0)`

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen very unlikely that the quotes are the issue. The comparison coerces to the higher class and if `b` is actually a `logical` vector, using the quotes is just a waste of computational time, but shouldn't change the result. Also, it's much better `ifelse(b, m, 0)` (no need to compare to `TRUE`).

Comment: @nicola I wouldn't be surprised, I just made that as a possible suggestion :-)

Comment: Hello Esma! To receive useful help, please see here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to have tips on how to ask a good question.

Comment: it actually worked . :) thanks